# Unlock screen lock on my Samsung Galaxy S5 - PIN code doesn't work

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, locked-out

First I pressed the button on Google Settings that says *remotely ring, lock & erase*  then I pressed the power button. After this my screen with locked (pin code) cones up. It doesn't open with my code, rather it says *pin code incorrect*.
When this occurred, I checked Google Android Device Manager, there is my phone Galaxy S5 registered in my Google mail but my internet connection, GPS and other things are all switched off in my phone.
But when I press the button there is a code that I didn't understand at that time, and I don't know it now. So how can I disable the lock?

Comment: You're being unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get access via the PIN code, you can sometimes use a much longer code called the [PUK code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_unblocking_code). This is the one you use if the phone locks due to having tried the wrong PIN code too often.

The PUK code comes with the phone, along with the PIN code. Find the original box; it will be there. Possibly on the card that your SIM card was attached to.